# what will be the type of class object where the class implements an interface and also has it own new members

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-types

I am new to OOP and typescript so here is the sample code

```
interface Company{
 compName:string;
 compId: number;
 compAdree:string;
}

class Employee implements Company{
 compName="fb";
 compId=83487;
 compAdree="NY";
 emp_name="peter";
 emp_id=99348493;
 emp_adr="Ny"
}
```

so in above code class Employee is implementing interface company the class has some new members which are not in the interface so if i create a object of the class Employee what will be the type of the object ?

I have came across some code where it is the class type and in some it is the interface type. So i am confused which to use

will it be

```
let emp:Employee = new Employee()
```

or will it be

```
let emp:Company = new Employee()
```

Comment: Both are valid. In second example you'll be allowed to use only members listed in the interface (e.g. `emp.compName` will be OK, but `emp.emp_adr` will error). In both cases the underlying object will have the same prototype/ properties

Comment: Your class code seems to be incorrect. Did you mean assignment to class fields instead of `:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat `Company` as a super type and `Employee` as a sub type. It means that `Employee` is assignable to `Company`.
Consider this example:

```js
interface Company {
  compName: string;
  compId: number;
  compAdree: string;
}

class Employee implements Company {
  compName: "fb";
  compId: 83487;
  compAdree: "NY";
  emp_name: "peter";
  emp_id: 99348493;
  emp_adr: "Ny"
}

declare let company: Company;
declare let employee: Employee;

company = employee // ok
```

but not vice versa:

```js
employee=company // error
```

Let's go back to the original example.
This line:

```js
let emp:Employee = new Employee()
emp.compName // ok
emp.emp_adr // ok
```

means that `emp` is allowed to use all properties from `Company` and `Employee`, whereas this line:

```js
let comp: Company = new Employee()
comp.compName // ok
comp.emp_adr // error
```

means that `comp` is allowed to use only `Company` properties despite the fact that it also contains `Employee` proper in runtime. It is like static restriction.

Please see [Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

Also you probably might have noticed that `Employee` is a class and it is used both in runtime and type scope. This is a special property of typescript classes and enums. They both might be used in both scopes.